# laravel - install datatable and toastr plugin

Tags: bower

I want to use datatable and toastr plugins on my project using laravel as my framework. should i include these on bower.json file? if so, what value should I put?

I can do this manually via **bower install (git location)** on the command prompt though, but I'm just wondering if I can do this on bower.json file so that I can just do the **bower install** command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to simply add them to the bower.json file, you can add them to `dependencies` like such:

```
{
    "name": "your-application-name",
    "dependencies": {
      "toastr": "^2.1.3",
      "datatables.net": "^1.10.16"
    }
}
```

If you're still interested in saving them to the bower.json file from the command line, you can do it by including the `--save` flag to your install command:

```
$ bower install --save toastr
$ bower install --save datatables.net
```

That will download the components as well as add them to the bower.json file.

Comment: your entry on the dependencies is EXACTLY what i am looking for. Thank you very much Chris! (salute)

Comment: Chris, can I ask on where did those command on the bower.json file is downloading the dependencies?

Comment: The dependencies toastr and datatables.net? I've updated my answer with a skeleton bower.json file to show where the dependencies section could reside. If that's not what you meant, could you please clarify?

Comment: i mean, on what website or URL did the bower.json is downloading these dependencies from? apologies for my english

Comment: It's alright; when you run the `bower install` command, the output shows where they get downloaded from (which happens to be from GitHub in both cases). You can see where a Bower package comes from before installing it by searching for it on Bower Search (https://bower.io/search/)

Comment: i already run the bower install command, and i saw that they indeed downloaded from github just as you said. is that really the default behavior? it always look at github?

Comment: It downloads from where the package maintainer wants to host it; you can see the steps that package maintainers take to register libraries with Bower here: https://bower.io/docs/creating-packages/#register. I'd hazard to guess that many maintainers host their code on GitHub.

Comment: thank you very much for your time! please feel good as you seriously have helped someone today. take care.